# Conditional pragmas in TwinCAT3

Tags: twincat

I have come accross the idea to use pragmas to make PLC code as easy to re-configure from machine to machine depending on what a particular machine requires (they are very similar, but still require to some work to make for every new project). The machine as a whole can contain N units, then you would just remove certain parts if new project does not need it. My idea was:

```
VAR_GLOBAL
        {attribute 'machinePart1'}
        {attribute 'machinePart2'}
        //{attribute 'machinePart3'} Lets say machine does not use attribute machinePart3
        machineParts : BOOL; // dummy variable to add attributes
END_VAR
```

In the PLC code, I would then use conditional pragmas for code parts that require or don't require certain parts - you would determin which attribute exists by commenting out unnecessary ones.

In the PLC the parts of the machine that are not present would then be disregarded like this:

```
{IF hasattribute (variable: machineParts, 'machinePart3')}
       //this code will not be executed
{END_IF}
{IF hasattribute (variable: machineParts, 'machinePart2')}
        //this code will be executed
{END_IF}
{IF hasattribute (variable: machineParts, 'machinePart1')}
        //this code will be executed
{END_IF}
```

So, my question is - is this a valid way to go about making a PLC code as easy to configure as possible? Does it affect efficency/CPU time? I havent looked deep into this, but I would assume the code is compiled, and for whatever conditional pragma the result is false, the code isn't complied and thus not present on the PLC itself when downloaded.

I would apply this to structures for machine parts and PLC code exectuion/function block instance creation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beckhoff already provides a solution for your requirements which is called variant management:

https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/variant_management/6325752587.html&id=

This does not affect performance as the compiled code only includes the variant that you have chosen.

Answer (score 1):

Jakob is right, there is already a variant management for the project level. And the link describes all necessary steps. The only thing to add here is a little advice from someone who has already fallen on his face with it several times. Be carefull with or rather just don't use the group feature (<=TC4024.20). The behaviour is really strange and very error-prone, from my point of view.

Comment: I have started a new machine startup and I will probably erase this... What is the point of groups if you cant activate configuration with a group selected, only a single variant works... It says so in documentation as well, maybe I don't see the bigger picture but it seems rather poinless when you cant group more variants for a single machine setup.

Comment: You can think of groups as an "editing filter". If you choose a group and make some changes, the changes will apply on all variants which are member of this group. If you change the same parameter with different group selection, last change wins. So it's not like an assembly of different variants or options. That's why you have to chose a explicit variant when compiling.